# How to get total number of pages of a PDF from a stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I know we can use a library like `pdf-parse` to extract `numpages` from a PDF buffer. I'm running into an issue where sometimes my buffers are way too large to be kept in memory. So I decided to stream it:

```
const response = await axios.get(file.href, {
    responseType: 'stream'
});

const stream = response.data;
 
stream.on('data', data => { 
    ...
});
```

Is there a library available that can help me parse a stream of buffers to extract number of pages much like `pdf-parse` does for single buffers?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you,

```
const axios = require('axios');
const PDFParser = require('pdf-parse');
const { Readable } = require('stream');

async function extractTextFromPDFStream(pdfUrl) {
  // Create a readable stream from the PDF file URL
  const response = await axios.get(pdfUrl, { responseType: 'stream' });
  const pdfStream = response.data;

  // Create a custom readable stream that emits chunks of data
  const customStream = new Readable({
    read(size) {
      // Read a chunk of data from the PDF stream
      const chunk = pdfStream.read(size);
      if (chunk !== null) {
        // Push the chunk to the custom stream
        this.push(chunk);
      } else {
        // Signal the end of the stream
        this.push(null);
      }
    },
  });

  // Initialize pdf-parse with the custom stream
  const pdfData = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks = [];
    const pdfParser = new PDFParser();
    
    pdfParser.on('pdfParser_dataError', (errData) => {
      reject(errData);
    });
    
    pdfParser.on('pdfParser_dataReady', (pdfData) => {
      resolve(pdfData);
    });

    customStream.pipe(pdfParser);
  });

  // Extracted text is available in pdfData.text
  return pdfData.text;
}

// Usage
const pdfUrl = 'https://example.com/large.pdf';
extractTextFromPDFStream(pdfUrl)
  .then((text) => {
    console.log(text);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error:', err);
  });
```

Comment: I am getting `PDFParser is not a constructor` error?